# inserting into boost bimap with many-to-many relationship

Tags: c++, boost, many-to-many, bimap

I'd like create a data structure that will describe a relation between posts and tags. Each post can have multiple tags and a tag can be applied to many posts.

Each post and tag can be uniquely identified by a key (let's say `int`).

I want to be able to efficiently get all the tags for a given post and all the posts of a given tag.

I want to move from a code that looks like this:

```
unordered_map<int, vector<int> > post_to_tags;
unordered_map<int, vector<int> > tags_to_post;
```

to `boost::bimap`. I've tried this:

```
typedef bimap<
    unordered_multiset_of<int>,
    unordered_multiset_of<int>,
    unconstrained_set_of_relation
> BimapType;

BimapType bm;
```

Without the `unconstrained_set_of_relation` the bimap would allow to insert the same (post, tag) pair more than once (since it uses a multiset for the relation). With the `unconstrained_set_of_relation` I am unable to figure out how to insert elements into this container (there's no insert defined).

1. Can `boost::bimap` describe this relationship at all?
2. How can insert be performed?
3. Is Boost.MultiIndex a better choice (easier to use/efficient) for this case?